# How do I select an option select and set it?

Tags: jquery

Here is what i have and here is the html...what am i doing wrong?

```
$("#request_showdate_1i option[value='2012']").attr("selected","selected");

  <select name="request[showdate(1i)]" id="request_showdate_1i">
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2010" selected="selected">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Is the question titled `When is the world gonna end?` :)

Comment: @marko lol, what made you think so :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
 $('#request_showdate_1i').val('2012');
```

jQuery will do the rest :)

See the second example here: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct (though Darryl Hein's answer is easier to type), so there must be some other problem.

Where is your JS code?

Is it inside a doc ready? ==> `$(function() { ... });

Is jQuery included, etc.

Here is a **[fully working HTML page](http://fiddle.jshell.net/QCZ3a/show/light/)**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title> - jsFiddle demo</title> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js'></script> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css"/> 

    <style type='text/css'> 
        body {
            background-color: transparent;
            padding: 10px;
        }

    </style> 
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
    //<![CDATA[ 

        $(function() {
    $("#request_showdate_1i option[value='2012']").attr("selected","selected");
});


    //]]> 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form> 
<select name="request[showdate(1i)]" id="request_showdate_1i"> 
<option value="2005">2005</option> 
<option value="2006">2006</option> 
<option value="2007">2007</option> 
<option value="2008">2008</option> 
<option value="2009">2009</option> 
<option value="2010" selected="selected">2010</option> 
<option value="2011">2011</option> 
<option value="2012">2012</option> 
<option value="2013">2013</option> 
<option value="2014">2014</option> 
<option value="2015">2015</option> 
</select> 
<form> 

</body> 


</html>
```