# Select an option of select box using the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown box and I want to select the option based on value. Somehow I am getting handle to value say `3`. Now I want to manually select the option which has got value `3`.

I have tried something like this

```
selectBoxElement.options[selectedValues].selected = true;
```

where `selectedValue = 3`, but it is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select an option select and set it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895400/how-do-i-select-an-option-select-and-set-it)

Answer (score 2):

If using jquery (as per your tag), you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourSelectId option[value='3']").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work (assuming `$` is not overwritten and is alias for `jQuery`):

```
$(selectBoxElement).find('option[value="selectedValue"]').prop('selected', true);
```

or rather:

```
$(selectBoxElement).val(selectedValue);
```

which is simpler and achieves similar result :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using plain JS (except for the jQuery tag, you didn't explicitly say whether you want plain JS or jQuery), this should do what you want:

```
for (i=0; i<selectBoxElement.options.length; i++) {
    if (selectBoxElement.options[i].value == selectedValues) {
      selectBoxElement.options[i].selected=true;
      break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple please try the following

When using the index position of the option tag within the select box 
**selectBoxElement.selectedIndex = index;** // Where the index starts from 0

When using the value 
**selectBoxElement.value = value;**// Where the value is the attribute defined within option tag

Hope this solves your problem.