# Complex select change on another select.. not asked before

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

My problem is fairly simple to explain yet a little tricky to implement. Logically it seems very possible but im a little stuck.

Objective/purpose:
I have my first SELECT named "hour" and a second SELECT named "rec_hour". Each have the same values. See HTML code below:

```
<select id="hour">
  <option value="0">00</option>
  <option value="1">01</option>
  <option value="2">02</option>
  <!-- This would go up to 23 -->
</select>

<select id="rec_hour">
   <option value="0">00</option>
   <option value="1">01</option>
   <option value="2">02</option>
 <!-- This would go up to 23 -->
</select>
```

I receive a variable from a PHP file "$hours" which contains a integer value ranging from 0 to 24. Now, I want to get that value of hours, lets say its 6 for this scenerio, and subtract this value in the second SELECT (rec_hour).

So in essence, if my returned variable is 6. and i choose say 10 from the first select (hour) then i want the second select to show/select the value that is 10-6 which is 4.

I hope that makes sense..

I have tried the script below out of desperation but to no avail:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#hour").change(function() {
        var myHour = $(this).val();
        var Subtra = 10;
        var recHour = myHour - Subtra;

       $("#rec_hour").val = recHour;
       $("#rec_hour").text(recHour); 
     }
  });

});
```

My code above im using "Subtra" as a litmus test value.. this would actually change based on my php result.

UPDATE:

All i really want to do is this..

I receive a time (hours only) say 2 -> refers to 2am (14 would be 2pm) n then my php will calculate hours to find out how long a journy will take. For instance say tht is 6 hours.. then i want to show the user 6 hours behind from 2am..which is 8pm.. i.e. you should leave home at 8pm.. you follow? or am i confusing?

Comment: So you're asking how to set the value of a `select` element using jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select an option select and set it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895400/how-do-i-select-an-option-select-and-set-it)

Comment: What if the value is negative?

Comment: Thats another problm initself, i may have a solution for that. but al i really want to do is this.. i receive a time (hours only) say 2 -- refers to 2am. n then my php wil lcalculate hours to find out how long a journy will take for instance n say tht is  hours.. then i want to show the user 6 hours behind from 2am..which is 8pm.. i.e. you shoudl leave hoe at 8pm.. you follow? or am i confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value of rec_hour using .val().  Also note there was a few syntax errors in your code. You had an extra curly brace.  Also you want to handle the case where subtra > myHour, using the abs value function.

Corrected Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#hour").change(function() {
        var myHour = $(this).val();
        var Subtra = 4;
        var recHour = Math.abs(Subtra - myHour);
       $("#rec_hour").val(recHour);
     });
});
```

Original With Errors Noted:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#hour").change(function() {
        var myHour = $(this).val();
        var Subtra = 10;
        var recHour = myHour - Subtra;  //handle Subtra > myHour with abs()

       $("#rec_hour").val = recHour;
       $("#rec_hour").text(recHour); 
     } //This curly brace is not needed
  });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FdW4w/3/

I gave some more descriptive variables names and applied the math.  The fiddle is also updated to reflect this.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#arrival").change(function() {
        var arrivalTime = $(this).val();
       $("#depart").val(getDepartTime(10, arrivalTime));
     });
});

      function getDepartTime(journeyDuration, arrivalTime){
          var departTime = 0;
          if(journeyDuration > arrivalTime){
             departTime = 24 - (Math.abs(journeyDuration - arrivalTime));             
          }else{
             departTime = arrivalTime -journeyDuration;
          }
          return departTime;
      }
```

Comment: I may not be handling your math with the hours correctly.  I'm a little unsure of what you want to accomplish with that

Comment: See my UPDATE comment at the top please.. better explaination. Thank you for your answers.. at least got one thing working..

Comment: Still not following the example.  I am not sure where you get each value, where does 2am come from? The first drop down?

Comment: Jhourney time is given in hours before this whole process is started. you can choose any number you like from 1-24. Then you pick the first select.. which is the hour you want to get to that place by.. say .. 13 (thats 1pm).. then i need to auto fill/seelct the rec_hour by saying.. first select - journey = rec_hour.. n show that to user..

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
$("#rec_hour").val(recHour);
```

Comment: This works but not consistenly. Basically where subtracting time (hours) right.. in your demo is doesnt alays work.. try changing the first select a few times and see..Also my sub isnt backwards.. if user selects 2 (that means 2am) n say variale returned is 6.. then the anser needs to be 6 hours behind from 2am.. that nother problem in itself

Comment: I don't think he has it backwards... I think `Subtra` is supposed to be the php value.

Comment: I read the subtraction part backwards, but it does work, I just didn't want to create 32 entries in the select, so if you pick 1 it just selects 0.  `val` works, always.

Comment: @TopDollarUK, it doesn't work because he doesn't have all of the values enumerated.  The code does what it is supposed to (other than being backwards).

Comment: Ah i see your point. and i udnerstand now. But the other prob is the negative value which is arghhhh lol. See my edit please..