# How to change the selected option of a select box using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I select an option select and set it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895400/how-do-i-select-an-option-select-and-set-it)

I have a select box defined as below.

```
<select @string.Format("id={0}", Model.FieldId) name="Id1" onclick="LoadIds('@string.Format("{0}", Model.FieldId)')">
    <option @string.Format("value={0}", row.ID1) selected="selected">@row.ID1</option>
</select>
```

All the options of the select box are loaded in the onclick event. When I launch the page, it is showing the appropriate value (as selected) in the select box and also the options are loaded fine from "LoadIds" function. Now I want to choose a different value from the dropdown and set the new value as selected. I guess I need to implement onchange event. My question is how to remove the selected attribute from the old option and add it to the new selected option?

Comment: *"I want to choose a different value from the dropdown"* Do you mean the user selects a different value? It will automatically be selected, you don't have to change the attribute. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, when the user selects a different value from the dropdown the new value appears and immediately changes back to the previous old value. I am not sure if it has anything to do with the jQuery datatable that is applied on the html table. I have the select box in a html table and I am displaying it as jquery datatable by applying .dataTable() extension in the $(document).ready function. Thank you.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo, this seems to be a rather strange situation.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery's `.val('valueHere')` on a select will make the active item in the dropdown to the value passed, if available.

```
<select id="a">
        <option val="1">One</option>
        <option selected="selected" val="2">Two</option>
        <option val="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$('#a').val('1');​
```

The `selected` attribute will still appear on Two but will not be selected. You don't need to remove that attribute, its just for the default selection. If you really wanted to see `.prop()` .

Warning of using `.removeProp()` on `selected` as noted in comments & the jQuery docs

> **Note**: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

Comment: just mentioning prop() should be good, because if they use .removeProp() on a property, they will no longer be use that property... from jQuery docs `This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.`

Comment: Good catch, I did not realize that caveat.