# Select Not Getting Set To Selected Value Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set a select to a specific option. I am creating my select with this code..

```
$('#drpSortBy').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", 'Application_ID').text('Application'));
$('#drpSortBy').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", 'Approver_ID').text('Approver'));
$('#drpSortBy').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", 'Days_Pending').text('Days Pending'));
$('#drpSortBy').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", 'Originator_ID').text('Originator'));
$('#drpSortBy').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", 'Title').text('Title'));
```

I am trying to set the select list to a specific option based on value with this code but it doesnt seem to be responding

```
 $('#drpSortBy option').val(userSort.SortFieldName).attr('selected', true);
```

I have verified that userSort.SortFieldName='Originator_ID' for testing purposes

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select an option select and set it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895400/how-do-i-select-an-option-select-and-set-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set selected value.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/kRx2J/)**

```
 $('#drpSortBy').val(userSort.SortFieldName)
```

Comment: this solution sets the selected value, then what else do u want?